# Apache 2.4 and FPM: Prohibit execution of php due to IP-Adresse

Tags: php, apache, apache2.4

Situation: Here we have an apache 2.4 with php-fpm

*vhost-Conf:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Content of */var/www/html/foo/.htaccess*

```
 <RequireAny>
  Require ip 10.34.
 </RequireAny>
```

Works fine with "flat files"; means:

http://server/foo/picture.png

is blocked by an 403-Forbidden error. Great! But....

*http://server/foo/myscript.php*

is cheerful executed and is shown in the browser. Unfortunately I have no idea how to prevent this.

Someone else maybe?

Comment: Try loosing the trailing `.` like `Require ip 10.34`

Comment: Also I dont think the `<RequireAny>` tag is actually required and may in fact be causing issues

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Neither omitting the dot nor the tag.